# Spin-charge separation and Spin-Statistics relations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, spin-statistics, partons

Usually, we associate the half-integer spin to fermion, and the integer spin to boson. And there are constraints like the [**Spin-Statistics relations**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem).

However, in [**Spin–charge separation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93charge_separation) or the **parton-construction techniques ([Schwinger/Abrikosov boson/fermions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63073), see also [other webpages](https://www.google.com/search?q=Schwinger%2FAbrikosov+boson%2Ffermions&oq=Schwinger%2FAbrikosov+boson))**, we can separate a spin-1/2 charge-1 fermion to a spinon (with spin-1/2) and a holon (or called chargeon, with a charge-1).

It terms out that a spinon (with spin-1/2) in [Spin–charge separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93charge_separation) may be:

(1) **bosonic spinon** (with spin-1/2)!

(2) fermionic spinon (with spin-1/2).

In (1), even a spin-1/2 object called the spinon can be a boson!!!

> I wonder **what are the constraints on the Spin-charge separation, and how does this tie to the Spin-Statistics relations (in any dimensions, especially in 2+1d and 3+1d)?**

Comment: The spin-statistics relations are compatible with the spin-charge separation, since the later appears in low dimensions. See e.g. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65767/what-is-the-reason-why-anyons-escape-spin-statistic-theorem for more details.

Comment: @FraSchelle, But obviously I think wonderich meant that he/she considers the Schwnger/Abrikosov parton construction as spin charge separation, which works in 2+1 and 3+1 dim too. Perhaps it can be used in any dims.

Comment: The two questions are different.

Comment: @mysteriousness As far as I can see, the wikipedia page refers only to low dimensional systems. If Wonderich wants to make an other point, (s)he should make a clear question with explicit citation :-)  Thank you anyways for the remark.

Comment: I think the Wikipage does not restrict to  1+1d. It only says 1+1d goes to Luttinger liquids (well-known.) Also he/she had referred to "parton-construction techniques (Schwinger/Abrikosov boson/fermions)." I am pretty sure that the community also uses that as Spin-charge separation.