# The Nambu spinor

Tags: condensed-matter

What is the reason behind using the weird minus sign in the fourth component of the extended Nambu basis? 
$$\Psi^{\dagger}=(\Psi_{i\uparrow}^{\dagger}\quad \Psi_{i\downarrow}^{\dagger} \quad \Psi_{i\downarrow}\quad-\Psi_{i\uparrow})$$
While it does allow neat expressions for certain tight-binding Hamiltonians in terms of pauli matrices(in either spin or p-h space) I am not sure if this really is the motivation.
Also, the spinor is not even the tensor product of particle-hole and spin components, so another question would be why the Nambu basis at all?

Comment: it looks eerily like a Minkowskian metric, but there is no obvious connection

Answer (score 2):

The minus sign in your spinor, sometimes known as the spinor with SO(4) symmetry, is inserted to enforce both the SU(2) spin and pseudospin symmetries. Basically to impose the $SU(2)_{s} \times SU(2)_{p}$ one should employ two doublets which based on your language are $D_{1}= (\Psi_{i \uparrow}^{\dagger} \quad \Psi_{i \downarrow})$ and $D_{2}= (\Psi_{i \downarrow}^{\dagger} \quad -\Psi_{i \uparrow})$ which can be also represented in a $2\times2$ matrix form, see also [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63368).

Answer (score 1):

The Nambu basis is just a useful representation for superconducting Hamiltonians. Is is, in fact, a tensor product between spin and particle-hole spaces, but not a trivial one. Take a look at [here](https://topocondmat.org/w2_majorana/nanowire.html) to see some of the usefulness and construction of such basis.

Comment: This doesn't seem to really answer the question.

Comment: it looks eerily like a Minkowskian metric, but there is no obvious connection

Comment: Maybe it doesn't seem to answer the question because it is not immediate to observe how this Nambu basis arrives. But if you fix a representation for time-reversal transformations for spin-half particles, you conclude that, in order to describe the Hamiltonian as in the section "Important and useful basis change" of the above link you must write the spinors as:
$$
\Psi^{\dagger} = (\xi^{\dagger}\ \  i \sigma_y \xi)
$$
with $\xi = (\psi_{\uparrow}\ \ \psi_{\downarrow})$. And there is your minus sign.

Comment: After the similarity transformation, the superconducting order parameter can be rewritten in a useful fashion with a singlet term proportional to $\sigma_0$ and the three triplet states proportional to the three Pauli matrices $\{\sigma_i\}_{i=1}^3$.